# How to appendChild in INPUT Form

Tags: javascript

[image]

Please see code below.how to appendChild in INPUT Form i have to get value in sql on one input type text and btn add function close each value.
I want all the information form appendChild to be in the form input.

Help me please.

example function not example code: https://jsfiddle.net/surveyjs/Ljnyaeva/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Ljnyaeva

```js
function select() {
    var t = document.createTextNode("X");
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 var ttt = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var container = document.createElement("INPUT");
    container.setAttribute("type", "text");
    container.setAttribute("value", ttt);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    document.body.appendChild(btn); 
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="select()">Try it</button>
<br>
<br>
<input id="demo" class="form-control">
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Pointy I want all the information form appendChild to be in the form input.

Comment: You need to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Then just append to the form node instead of `document.body`

Comment: @Pointy document.body.appendChild(container);  edit to document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(container); not working

Comment: No, append it to the `<form>`; you cannot append elements to an `<input>`

Comment: @Pointy you can modify code. i'm not understand

Comment: example function not example code: https://jsfiddle.net/surveyjs/Ljnyaeva/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Ljnyaeva

Comment: Your example is about a DIV element; not a INPUT Element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, there are alot of libraries out there solving the problem "multiple predifined values to append to a text input field" like this: 
https://dbrekalo.github.io/fastselect/#section-Examples

This is a common scenario and alot of people spent time building ready to use versions, so I would not recommend you to try to build your own unless you really want to do it.

In your example you are trying creating a new input instead of using the one already in your DOM.

```
function select() {
   var ttt = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
   var existingInput = document.getElementById("demo");
   if(existingInput.value!=""){
    existingInput.value+=", ";
   }
   existingInput.value+=ttt
}

<form>
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option>
<option value="Banana">Banana</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="select()">Try it</button>
<br>
<br>
<input id="demo" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Just make it simpler. You don't need to append the selected item from the dropdown box because it will only create another text box.

```js
let $clearText = document.getElementById("clear-text");
let $container = document.getElementById("demo");
let $select = document.getElementById("mySelect");

function select() {
   var curentValue = $select.value;
   
    $container.setAttribute("type", "text");
    $container.setAttribute("value", curentValue);
   
   $clearText.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block");
}

function clearText() {
  $container.setAttribute("value", "");
  $clearText.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="select()">Try it</button>
<br>
<br>
<input id="demo" class="form-control">
<button type="button" onclick="clearText()" id="clear-text" style="display:none">X</button>
```